# How can you get the path to a user's home directory in Clojurescript running on Node?

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

You can't use `~` in paths for NodeJS functions because that's a bash-specific thing. So how do you get the path to a user's home directory in Clojurescript (on Node)?

Answer (score 1):

```clj
(def os (node/require "os"))

(.homedir os)
```

And to combine it with an additional path:

```clj
(def path (node/require "path"))

(.join path (.homedir os) "/directory/file.txt")
```